# add a new environment system variable through installshield script

Tags: visual-c++, batch-file, installshield

I want to add or create a new system environment variable through installshield script(5.5).
Can any body helps me How can I add a new environment variable through installshield script in windows 7 and XP?

Comment: Please show the code you already have.